# An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for xxx.hosting-data.io failed: Unknown Host

Tags: database, doctrine, symfony6, connexion, ionos

I want to connect my IONOS database to a Symfony6 project but I have this error :
`An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for xxx.hosting-data.io failed: Hôte inconnu.`
I tested the database in native PHP and I can connect fine.

Here is my .env file configuration:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://my-db-username:my-pwd@xxx.hosting-data.io:3306/my-db-name"
```

IONOS couldn't help me, can you?

I tested the database in native PHP and I can connect fine.